# Binding onbeforeunload and unload and removing the other once one fires

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am using onbeforeunload but i understand on safari you can't run an ajax with it... I need to do that. So, for those browser that don't support unbeforeunload, I'll use unload.. but, I don't want two firings of my ajax for those browsers that support both.

So, just to be clear. I need to fire an ajax request once the user "leaves/refreshes" the page. I need a solid way in most popular browsers and ie8+.

Can someone help me out on how I can remove the other binding once one fires?

ala

```
window.addListener('onbeforeunload', function(){
    // run ajax

})

window.addListender('unload', function(){
    // run ajax
})
```

whichever listener fires first, fires and then unbinds the other that is set. I am thinking that i don't want to unbind "all" unloads or onbeforeunloads on my site/page.. just the ones i set.. Can I set a namespace like you can in jQuery? ala... onbeforeunload.myBind etc...

Any help would be unappreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you can do this:

```
$(document).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    // ajax
    $(document).unbind('unload');
}).bind('unload', function () {
    //ajax
    $(document).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Comment: I apologize I can't upvote you. Not enough rep yet. But thank you!